# Xunit Unit Tests will not run

Tags: c#, .net, windows-10, visual-studio-2017, xunit

I am completely stuck on this issue. So my team has a unit test project in a services test project. The tests are discovered in the test explorer pane however when I try and run the tests I get these errors:

> 'Multiple test adapters with the same uri
>   'executor://xunit/VsTestRunner2' were found. Ignoring adapter
>   'Xunit.Runner.VisualStudio.TestAdapter.VsTestRunner'. Please uninstall
>   the conflicting adapter(s) to avoid this warning'
>
> '[xUnit.net 00:00:00.0251250] Skipping:  (could not find
>   dependent assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel,
>   Version=1.1.0')'
>
> 'No test is available in C:\. Make sure that test
>   discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version
>   settings are appropriate and try again.'

Context information:

- Xunit 2.2.0
- Visual Studio 15.5.2
- Windows 10 1709 Build: 16299.125

My Test Projects project.json:

```
{
   "version": "1.0.0-*",
   "testRunner": "xunit",
    "dependencies": {
       "dotnet-test-xunit": "2.2.0-preview2-build1029",
       "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures": "1.1.3",
       "Microsoft.DiaSymReader": "1.0.8",
       "Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native": "1.4.1",
       "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions": "1.1.2",
       "Microsoft.Extensions.Testing.Abstractions": "1.0.0-preview2-003121",
       "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1",
       "WebServices": "1.0.0-*",
       "xunit": "2.2.0",
       "xunit.abstractions": "2.0.1",
       "xunit.assert": "2.2.0",
       "xunit.core": "2.2.0",
       "xunit.extensibility.core": "2.2.0",
       "xunit.extensibility.execution": "2.2.0",
       "xunit.runner.utility": "2.2.0"
   },
   "frameworks": {
    "net461": {
        "dependencies": {
            "Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms": "1.1.0"
        }
    }
}
```

The Weird thing is that it works for my team members. But not me. The differences in our environments are: the latest update from Windows and Visual Studio, while they are an update or two behind.

Does anyone know of a workaround?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by updating Visual Studio 2017 from 15.5.2 to 15.5.4 and updating my test project references from:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.3.0-preview-20170628-02" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.2.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

to:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.3.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

And restarting Visual Studio (apparently VS caches and uses the previous version even after you've updated).

Not sure if one of the 3 things or the combination of them fixed it.

Comment: Thank you ! That was rather an annoying issue!

Comment: The official documentation obviously wasn't tested: https://github.com/dotnet/samples/tree/master/core/getting-started/unit-testing-using-dotnet-test

Comment: However this trick doesn't work in Visual Studio 2017 for .net core projects

Comment: <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.3.0-preview-20170628-02" />   fix it.

Comment: The Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk was required in VS 2022 with .net 6 and xunit. I also added xunit.runner.visualstudio.

Answer (score 61):

Installing or updating "xunit.runner.visualstudio" package did the trick for me.  Until that, it was not working with framework 462.

Comment: You saved my time, I moved from MS Tests to xunit and it was showing message "tests are not discovered".. adding xunit.runner.visualstudio, solved my issue.. Thanks !

Answer (score 13):

I encountered the same issue, but I have already had Visual Studio 2017 15.5.4 installed. In order to make it work I updated all `xunit` related references and now my .csproj relevant references look like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.5.0" />
   <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.3.1" />
   <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.2.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Not really sure what was not working, but my advice is to make sure that these reference are within csproj and have these minimum versions.

Comment: Do you have netcore project ?

Comment: @alerya - yes, I do. The OP suggests also .NET Core also due to project.json.

Comment: Thanks you help me

Answer (score 4):

I was having a similar issue as yours, stating `could not find dependent assembly`; when in fact, that assembly was there and available to the xUnit VS runner. However, what the actual issue was, I had Visual Studio set to use the `32bit` test runner by default. The 'dependent assembly' it couldn't find was simply a different processor architecture than the xUnit test runner being used.

To fix, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/1304), from the Visual Studio menu, go to `Test -> Test Settings -> Default Processor Architecture` and set that to `X64` if you are using `64bit` assemblies, or `X86` if you are using `32bit` assemblies. The error that the xUnit VS runner gives is very misleading to try to debug this issue.

This issue I saw when installing Visual Studio on a new machine. The tests would run on my desktop maching in Visual Studio, but not on my laptop.

Comment: Actually my assemblies are all for "Any CPU"

Comment: And also I changed these default Architectures! Nothing helps

Comment: All of my assemblies are also 'Any CPU'. Unfortunately, I never found a real reason for the issue. :-(

Comment: Seems, this issue from Visual Studio, and faster just to reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

Close and reopen Visual Studio works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a project running on the same Visual Studio (or any other instance of Visual Studio), please stop it. Although I know it's awkward, it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your issue in Visual Studio is that the Test Runner output seems empty, check that the relevant buttons (white boxes, below) are all selected.

[image: Check the white boxes]

Answer (score -1):

I had same issue, I installed below nuget packages

```
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.10.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.3">
```

Comment: How does your answer differ or add value to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48333576/109702)? Or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49526097/109702)? Or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48445354/109702)? Other than version numbers your answer is basically identical, so edit an existing answer if you have value to add, or consider not answering if you've got nothing new.

Answer (score -1):

Encountered this problem on VS 2019 recently.
Installing VS.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework nuget fixed the issue

Comment: Wlecome to the site! What you suggested has already been covered in at least three or four answers on this question, so consider upvoting one of the existing answers rather than effectively repeating what has already been said.