# Can't run Xunit tests on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, testing, xunit, test-runner

Can't run all the XUnit tests on my Visual Studio 2017. `Version 15.6.4`

They can be viewed in TestExploer and when I run them from there I get something like this:

```
[27.03.2018 12:21:46 Informational] ------ Load Playlist started ------
[27.03.2018 12:21:46 Informational] ========== Load Playlist finished 
(0:00:00,0215566) ==========
[27.03.2018 12:22:27 Informational] Executing test method 'Lebara.Remittance.Test.ServiceImplementation.RiskEngineServiceTest.ShouldTest'
[27.03.2018 12:22:27 Informational] ------ Run test started ------
[27.03.2018 12:22:29 Warning] Multiple test adapters with the same uri 
'executor://xunit/VsTestRunner2' were found. Ignoring adapter 
'Xunit.Runner.VisualStudio.TestAdapter.VsTestRunner'. Please uninstall the 
conflicting adapter(s) to avoid this warning.
[27.03.2018 12:22:29 Warning] [xUnit.net 00:00:00.0209459] Skipping: 
Lebara.Remittance.Test (could not find dependent assembly 
'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel, Version=1.1.0')
[27.03.2018 12:22:29 Warning] No test is available in C:\ReposNew\Lebara.Remittance\Lebara.Remittance\Lebara.Remittance.Test\bin\Debug\Lebara.Remittance.Test.dll. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
[27.03.2018 12:22:29 Informational] ========== Run test finished: 0 run 
(0:00:02,1543479) ==========
[27.03.2018 12:34:19 Informational] Executing test method 'Lebara.Remittance.Test.ServiceImplementation.RiskEngineServiceTest.ShouldTest'
[27.03.2018 12:34:19 Informational] ------ Run test started ------
[27.03.2018 12:34:20 Warning] Multiple test adapters with the same uri 
'executor://xunit/VsTestRunner2' were found. Ignoring adapter 
'Xunit.Runner.VisualStudio.TestAdapter.VsTestRunner'. Please uninstall the 
conflicting adapter(s) to avoid this warning.
[27.03.2018 12:34:20 Warning] [xUnit.net 00:00:00.0200861] Skipping: 
Lebara.Remittance.Test (could not find dependent assembly 
'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel, Version=1.1.0')
[27.03.2018 12:34:20 Warning] No test is available in C:\ReposNew\Lebara.Remittance\Lebara.Remittance\Lebara.Remittance.Test\bin\Debug\Lebara.Remittance.Test.dll. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
[27.03.2018 12:34:20 Informational] ========== Run test finished: 0 run 
(0:00:00,7088116) ==========
```

I tried deleting `%TEMP%\VisualStudioTestExplorerExtensions` - nothing helped.

The thing is, several days ago I could run them. I did not change a thing. Just have no idea what is going on.

Also I had this warning

```
 [27.03.2018 12:22:29 Warning] Multiple test adapters with the same uri 
 'executor://xunit/VsTestRunner2' were found. Ignoring adapter 
 'Xunit.Runner.VisualStudio.TestAdapter.VsTestRunner'. Please uninstall the 
 conflicting adapter(s) to avoid this warning.
 [27.03.2018 12:22:29 Warning] [xUnit.net 00:00:00.0209459] Skipping: 
 Lebara.Remittance.Test (could not find dependent assembly 
 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel, Version=1.1.0')
```

Comment: Let me guess, you updated to the latest preview version of xUnit ? You'll have to uninstall it *and* manually remove it from the solution *and* the nuget cache in `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages`.

Answer (score 17):

I had problems with xUnit. Some important things:

1) Make sure the "Microsoft Visual Studio Test Platform" extension is enabled

2) Make sure "Test => Test Settings => Default Processor Architecture" matches your build.

3) Install nuget package 'xunit.runner.visualstudio'

Comment: Enabling "Microsoft Visual Studio Test Platform" extension is what seemed to do it for me.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using .NET Core or ASP.NET Core, then from xunit (https://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dotnet-core.html):

> Running tests with Visual Studio
>
> If you're having problems discovering or running tests, you may be a
>   victim of a corrupted runner cache inside Visual Studio. To clear this
>   cache, shut down all instances of Visual Studio, then delete the
>   folder %TEMP%\VisualStudioTestExplorerExtensions. Also make sure your
>   solution is only linked against a single version of the Visual Studio
>   runner NuGet package (xunit.runner.visualstudio).
>
> If you have Visual Studio Community (or a paid-for version of Visual
>   Studio), you can run your xUnit.net tests within Visual Studio's
>   built-in test runner (named Test Explorer). Unfortunately, this does
>   not include Express editions of Visual Studio (you should upgrade to
>   the free Community Edition instead).
>
> Right click on the project in Solution Explorer and choose Manage
>   NuGet Packages. You will need to install two packages:
>
> ```
> xunit.runner.visualstudio (version 2.3.1 or later)
> Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk (version 15.0.0 or later; we recommend using whatever the latest RTM build is)
> ```
>
> Make sure Test Explorer is visible (go to Test > Windows > Test
>   Explorer). Every time you build your project, the runner will discover
>   unit tests in your project. After a moment of discovery, you should
>   see the list of discovered tests:
>
> Click the Run All link in the Test Explorer window, and you should see
>   the results update in the Test Explorer window as the tests are run:
>
> You can click on a failed test to see the failure message, and the
>   stack trace. You can click on the stack trace lines to take you
>   directly to the failing line of code.

Also mentions

> Running tests against multiple targets

(if some projects target Core and others target .NET 4.5 for example.)

**Another possibility:**

Ensure using xunit 2.3.0+

Comment: The OP isn't asking how to run xUnit tests in general.

Comment: These are solutions found from the error:

"Multiple test adapters with the same uri 
'executor://xunit/VsTestRunner2' were found. Ignoring adapter 
'Xunit.Runner.VisualStudio.TestAdapter.VsTestRunner'."

Comment: You posted a copy of the documentation explaining how to run tests from Test Explorer. That's not what the OP asked about. There's nothing related to multiple or wrong test adapters. The OP could *already* runs tests from Test Explorer.

Comment: It's not explaining how to run tests, but when there are issues i.e. what to do when your test won't run; clearing the VisualStudioTestExplorerExtensions folder, ensuring using the same version of the runner, another section regarding compiling against multiple targets, and finally, updating the version of xunit.

Answer (score 4):

I run into the problem a couple of weeks ago when I upgraded xUnit to `2.4.0-beta.1`. Visual Studio's Test Explorer picked up *both* xUnit test adapters and failed with the above message.

Unfortunately, it wasn't a simple matter of [upgrading to the latest VS update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47894776/xunit-unit-tests-will-not-run) as I was already running the latest. I was already using the latest version of the `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk` package too. Downgrading to the latest stable version `2.3.1` didn't work either, VS was *still* picking both adapters.

In the end, I had to manually delete the version specific `xUnit` folders from the solution's packages folder *and* NuGet's cache at `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages`.

The [Clearing local folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) in `Managing the global packages, cache, and temp folders` should help too. If you have a fast internet connection, you may want to try the "nuke it" command:

```
nuget locals all -clear
```