# Xunit test does not run

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2019, xunit

I saw [Xunit Unit Tests will not run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47894776/xunit-unit-tests-will-not-run?rq=1) that seems specific to VS 2017. I am having the same problem with VS 2019. I can try to run the test via the Test Explorer or run the tests by right clicking on the test. Either way the test never runs. I have tried Debug an setting a breakpoint at the first line of the test. The breakpoint never gets hit. Similaryly I have tried debugging the test from the Test Explorer. Even if I bypass debug and just run the test the result always shows as "Not Run". I am not sure why the test will not run. None of the steps for VS 2017 seem to make a difference for VS 2019. How can I get my test to run?

Answer (score 0):

If you are compiling `x64` there is an option to run tests with a specific platform in the test menu. Change selection from `x86` to `x64`.

Comment: Maybe I set the wrong setting bug this didn't seem to have any effect. I changed the setting in the test project under 'Build' from 'Any CPU' to x64. That was the closest setting I could see. But like I said it didn't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50571848/7572443. It may not be the setting you need but it has been the issue for me many times.